# Autostart python script with feedback

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-idle, autostart, rc

On a Raspberry Pi I have a script that I want to auto-start on boot. I can get this to work with rc.local but it runs in the background. I want to have feedback from my script so that I know it is running error free at a glance.

Can I get Python(IDLE) to open/execute on startup and run a command? (Command: >>>import autostart)

I am sure this is must be posted else where but I am not sure how to ask the right questions.

Comment: why don't you add logging?

Comment: I didn't know about it until now ty. It looks like something I need to start using but (correct me if wrong) it still doesn't let me know the state my script is in at a glance since I would have to open a log file.

Comment: you have a startup script on your raspberry pi, and it runs in the background so you can't see logs? Maybe in the startup script add a command to bring it to the foreground?